# How to search a Dictionary with the contents of a list

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a todo file (todo.txt) which looks like this :

- Call Tom about the Foo project
- Complete the summary of the Bar project and send it to Thomas
- Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project

I would like to be able to write these tasks and have Vim append to each line the corresponding categories (@ for persons, & for projects) :

Tom (or Thomas) should generate @Tom, 
Susan should generate @Susan, 
Foo should generate &Foo and Bar &Bar

The outcome thus should be :

- Call Tom about the Foo project @Tom &Foo
- Complete the summary of the Bar project and send it to Thomas @Tom &Bar
- Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project @Susan @Tom & Foo

I have created a Dictionary :

```
let dictodo = {'Tom': "@Tom", 'Thomas': "@Tom", 'Susan': "@Susan", 'Foo': "&Foo", 'Bar': "&Bar",}
```

How can I each time I create a new task and leave Insert mode in this specific file have an autocommand launch a function (:autocmd InsertLeave todo.txt :call Filltodo() ?)

1) which will create a list with the different words of the line : I suppose

```
let words = split(getline('.'), '\W\+')
```

2) browse the dictodo Dictionary with this list

3)  and append the words that have a correspondance in the Dictionary (the **result** of 2) to the end of the line ? I suppose

```
call setline(line('.'), getline('.') . ' ' . result)
```

If I am not mistaken with my solutions for 1) and 3), then 2) is the missing part (I tried keyvar but failed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function! s:AppLine(pairs, line)
    let pairs=copy(a:pairs)
    let r=a:line
    for word in split(a:line, '\W\+')
        if has_key(pairs, word)
            let tag=remove(pairs, word)
            call filter(pairs, 'v:val isnot# tag')
            let r.=' '.tag
        endif
    endfor
    return r
endfunction
function! AddCat(pairs)
    return setline('.', s:AppLine(a:pairs, getline('.')))
endfunction
```

Usage:

```
%call AddCat(dictodo)
```

Comment: @romainl Thank you very much for your answers. I have tried them and chose to approve El Isra's answer because it treated all lines in one move (of course, I know the other two answers could be modified to do that, too). May I add that I am a truly novice vimscripter (romainl seems to exaggerate a little...) and I cannot decide between your - very technical - arguments. Thank you for  your help.

Comment: @ThG If you used `%call AddCat(dictodo)` like I suggested (note the per cent sign) or just the same with @romainl answer they will also do exactly the same thing. @Raimondi answer is to be modified if you *don’t* want to process all lines in one turn, ours are not.

Comment: of course, you were right. Thank you so much. How can I credit you with the right answer ?

Comment: Well, found out that I could do it. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Something like this function:

```
function! AddCat(pairs)
  let lines = []
  for line in getline(1,'$')
    let pairs = copy(a:pairs)
    let words = split(line, '\W\+')
    let cats = []
    " Looks for a category for every word and add it only once.
    call map(words,
          \'has_key(pairs, v:val) && index(cats, pairs[v:val]) == -1'
          \ . '? add(cats, pairs[v:val])'
          \ . ': ""')
    " Add the categories if non-empty.
    call add(lines, join([line]+cats))
  endfor
  call setline(1, lines)
endfunction

Define your pairs:

let dictodo = {'Tom': "@Tom", 'Thomas': "@Tom", 'Susan': "@Susan", 'Foo': "&Foo", 'Bar': "&Bar",}
```

And call it like this:

```
:call AddCat(dictodo)
```

**Note:** @ZyX's answer is much easier to understand than mine and I even used his suggestions on mine. Go and take a look by yourself.

Comment: : Thank you very much for your answer which works and furthermore treats all lines in one move.

Comment: I would have used `map(filter(, has_key), a:pairs[v:val])`. You last variant is best for perfomance, but difference between all three including my are likely to be insignificant unless there is too much data in the todo (amount of data in dictodo does not make the difference, unless using @romainl answer). I’ve chosen a loop because I use `remove()` to handle duplicate keys and using three-line function with a `map()` with two side-effects is a bit cryptic for an answer to novice vimmer.

Comment: I stumbled on a difficulty : how can I remove duplicate "labels" ? If I have put inside my Dictionary 'Tom': "@work" and 'Susan': "@work", and if I write Call Tom and Susan, @work will appear twice..

Comment: @ZyX I agree with you in all points, but I haven't change my answer since you already provide one so nice, I'm just pointing them to yours.

Comment: By the way, `line . (empty(cats) ? '' : ' ' . join(cats, ' '))` == `join([line]+cats)` (space is the default separator).

Comment: Right! That's a much cleaner solution. I'm not sure why, but for split() and join() I'm never sure if the default is an empty string or a space. Which shouldn't be a problem since :h join() is so easy to type.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use a list instead of a dict.

This quick and naive function seems to do what you want based on the building blocks you provided in your question. Be careful, though: the variables are not correctly scoped and it doesn't check if there are already some tags in place.

```
function! TidyTodo()
  let listodo = [['Tom','@Tom'],['Thomas','@Tom'],['Susan','@Susan'],['Foo','&Foo'],['Bar','&Bar']]
  let words = split(getline('.'), '\W\+')
  let appendix = ''
  for word in words
    for item in listodo
      if word == item[0]
        let appendix = appendix . ' ' . item[1]
      endif
    endfor
  endfor
  call setline(line('.'), getline('.') . appendix)
endfunction
```

Comment: What?! There is `has_key`, no need in two cycles.

Comment: My variant utilizing `has_key` is not naive? By the way, only my solution is not allowing duplicate tags (assuming you don’t have Tom and Thomas in one line) (not checking for already existing tags as well).

Comment: I am objecting here because dictionary is a good choice for holding such data and `items()`-like list is not. “What?!” == “Why are you using structure that just adds problems for no reason?!”

Comment: Answer: because I'm a novice "vimscripter". I'm not at all familiar with Vim's data structures and functions like `has_key()`. But I'm learning! And no. your variant is not "naive" at all. Your two answers taught me about `has_key()`, `map()`and `filter()` which will no doubt be handy.

Comment: Never thought of you as of novice vimscripter: too much replies on the vim tag to think so. And `map()`/`filter()` are not in my only answer to this question (though they are handier then I thought at the start: I sometimes use them to replace cycles: making use of side-effects of `add()`/`remove()`/`extend()`/`insert()` in these functions’ second arguments improves performance, sometimes significantly, at a cost of making code more cryptic).

Comment: Novice "vimscripter" yes, novice "vimmer" yes as well. Only 2 years of usage but a lot of enthusiasm! Thanks again for the explanation.