# Sort lines by "labels" and append the output after the lines

Tags: vim

I have just posted a question about ["How to search a Dictionary with the contents of a list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620603/how-to-search-a-dictionary-with-the-contents-of-a-list), and received answers by El Isra, romainl and Zyx which solved the question.

But it occurred to me (in a todo list point of view) that it might be interesting to display the results in a specific way, ie, views by categories (or "labels") created.

The resulting lines were :

```
Call Tom about the Foo project @Tom &Foo
Complete the summary of the Bar project and send it to Thomas &Bar @Tom
Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project @Susan @Tom &Foo
```

Is it possible in Vim to display those results after the lines by category (or "label") this way (separated by blank line) :

```
Call Tom about the Foo project @Tom &Foo
Complete the summary of the Bar project and send it to Thomas &Bar @Tom
Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project @Susan @Tom &Foo

@Tom
Call Tom about the Foo project &Foo
Complete the summary of the Bar project and send it to Thomas &Bar
Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project @Susan &Foo

@Susan
Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project @Tom &Foo

&Foo
Call Tom about the Foo project @Tom
Have Susan send me and Tom her forecasts for the Foo project @Susan @Tom

&Bar
Complete the summary of the Bar project and send it to Thomas @Tom
```

In fact, I remembered this was the way ("views") [Lotus Agenda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Agenda) proceeded, although in a much more sophisticated way...

Comment: It appears you're trying to manage todo lists in Vim. Have you tried any of the todo or org-mode plugins? Also, it might be better to use a separate application that already offers all these sorting and reporting capabilities. I can highly recommend http://todotxt.com/, it has a Bash/Cygwin-CLI, mobile, and many native clients.

Comment: In fact, not only. This can be useful for todo lists, of course, but it can be useful in many other ways. Suppose I write (I do not code at all) the history of a family (or a novel) : x characters, y places, z years. It would be interesting to be able to verify from time to time if things are logical and coherent. There are, of course, specialized tools for that, but you see, I appreciate the Vim way (you reminded me of it the other day ...). An other reason is that I really liked the Lotus Agenda way. I hope this answers your - justified - remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'd actually want those grouped results inserted into the original todo file, but rather have a filtered, separate list. For that, the quickfix list is ideal.

I would write a function that iterates over a passed list of categories, and performs `:vimgrepadd` commands over your todo list, resulting in the following calls:

```
:vimgrep /@Tom/ %
:vimgrepadd /@Susan/ %
:vimgrepadd ...
```

This gets you all occurrences grouped by category in the quickfix list, which you can open via `:copen`. Now, what's still missing is any segregation of the categories. You could use `setqflist()` to insert separator lines, but I would probably store the number of quickfix elements after each `:vimgrep` and then build a custom `'foldexpr'` that uses these line numbers to fold each category. It's a bit of implementation effort, but you've asked for something outside the usual realm of text editing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer : I shall test it and report in another message. BTW, I forgot to send you the Lotus Agenda reference (not the software, but an article about it), which shows this is not just a PIM : http://www.bobnewell.net/agenda/atlantic.txt.html

Comment: After trying, I think your answer is a satisfactory tradeoff considering my level in Vim (I don't want and can't build a contraption...). Nevertheless, I have 2 (minor) problems 1) how can I integrate the word under the cursor (e.g. Tom in :vimgrep /Tom/ %) in a function ? 2) the Quickfix output is (purposefully) built thus : filename|line number|column number|the item itself ; but I mean to use your solution only in the present buffer : is it possible to only keep the number of the line and the item itself ?

Comment: 1) `:vimgrep <cword> %` (without the slashes); 2) you can use the conceal feature for that; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199068/how-to-format-vim-quickfix-entry

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is possible to do this in Vim, I think tasks like these are better done in another programming language for the sake of **decoupling**: Vim scripts are only meant to be used to enhance some part of the editors functionality. That's for example why Vim doesn't have a built-in `sort` command (update: it actually does now in Vim 7): because this command does a task that is also useful in combination with other editors/commands.

If you create a set of Python/Perl scripts to do this text processing for you (which are arguably better text-processing languages than Vimscript), it would be easy to combine them with Vim, for example:

```
:%!python myscript.py
```

Would send the entire contents of the current buffer to `myscript.py` and replace the buffer with the results. You could also take a look at `:help read!`.

Comment: I agree; domain-specific tools (whether an off-the-shelf todo manager or a set of custom scripts) are better; said that in a comment already. I would only do this in Vim(script) if I only need this functionality in Vim, which (for a todo list) is far-fetched.

Comment: Ahem, since Vim 7, it has `:sort` built-in. We don't live in an idealized world; often pragmatism wins over purity.

Comment: You have a good point! I changed my answer to correct the mistake you found.